# Button didn't show up when menu value is set and shows odd style when not set

Tags: c, winapi, button, parent

I'd like to set a specific window as the parent of a button, but I'm getting an expected behavior.

When the `hMenu` value on `CreateWindow()` is set, the button don't show up:

[image]

```
CreateWindow(L"Button",
                            L"Click me!",
                            WS_TABSTOP,
                            20, 
                            50,
                            60,
                            90,
                            NULL, 
                            (HMENU)1, 
                            NULL, NULL);
```

But when I remove the `hMenu` parameter, the button does show up, but in a odd style:

[image]

```
CreateWindow(L"Button",
                        L"Click me!",
                        WS_TABSTOP,
                        20, 
                        50,
                        60,
                        90,
                        NULL, 
                        NULL, 
                        NULL, NULL);
```

I'm not passing the `HWND` returned by the `CreateWindow()` of the main window into `hwndParent` of the button because they aren't called in that order.

The below code is a reduced version from my real one.

What am I missing?

Full code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdi32.lib")

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

  MSG  msg = {0};
  WNDCLASSW wc = {0};

  wc.lpszClassName = L"Window";
  wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
  wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
  wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
  wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
  
  RegisterClassW(&wc);
  
  HWND
  hwndMainWindow = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, L"Window",
                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 350, 
                    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    HWND hButton = CreateWindow(L"Button",
                                L"Click me!",
                            WS_TABSTOP,
                            20, 
                            50,
                            60,
                            90,
                            NULL, 
                            NULL, 
                            NULL, NULL); 

    SetParent(hButton, hwndMainWindow);
    ShowWindow(hButton, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hwndMainWindow);

  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  
  return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

  switch(msg)
  {
      case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;

      case WM_DESTROY:
          PostQuitMessage(0);
          return 0;
  }

  return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not specifying the `WS_CHILD` style on the button.  `SetParent()` does not set this style for you.

When you set the "parent" of a window that does not have `WS_CHILD`, you are actually setting its "owner" instead.  [Owner and Parent are not the same thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/what-is-a-window-#parent-windows-and-owner-windows).  Also see [A window can have a parent or an owner but not both](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100315-00/?p=14613).

Your button does not appear in the main window because the button is not a child of the main window.

So, when creating the button, you need to include the `WS_CHILD` style.  You should also include the `WS_VISIBLE` style instead of using `ShowWindow()` (unless you want to create the button hidden initially).  And you should specify the parent window at the time of creation, instead of using `SetParent()`.

You should also move your button creation into the `WM_CREATE` handler of your main window's `WndProc()`.

Try this:

```c
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdi32.lib")

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

  MSG  msg = {0};
  WNDCLASS wc = {0};

  wc.lpszClassName = L"Window";
  wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
  wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
  wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
  wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
  
  RegisterClass(&wc);
  
  HWNDhwndMainWindow = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, L"Window",
                           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 350, 
                           NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

  ShowWindow(hwndMainWindow, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  UpdateWindow(hwndMainWindow);

  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  
  return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch(msg)
  {
      case WM_CREATE:
          CreateWindow(L"Button",
                       L"Click me!",
                       WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
                       20, 
                       50,
                       60,
                       90,
                       hwnd,
                       (HMENU)1, 
                       NULL, NULL); 
          break;

      case WM_COMMAND:
          if ((LOWORD(wParam) == 1) && (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)) {
              MessageBox(hwnd, L"Yea, you clicked me!", L"Window", MB_OK);
              return 0;
          }
          break;

      case WM_CLOSE:
          DestroyWindow(hwnd);
          break;

      case WM_DESTROY:
          PostQuitMessage(0);
          return 0;
  }

  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Relevant documentation: [Child Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#child-windows).